# Extent property is not working with openlayers tile layer

Tags: openlayers, extents, vector-tiles

I have an application where the images are load through the tiles, and I successfully made the tiles and was able to show them on the map.
But never was able to set the extent of the tile layer. 
Every time I set the properties, the layer doesn't load for the map.

```
 var mapSource = new ol.source.OSM({
    url: layerUrl    /// Local Tile Source
});
var mapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: mapSource,
    zIndex: 1,
    visible: true,
    //   extent: extent,    ///Comment Line 1
});

//  mapLayer.setExtent(extent);   ///Comment Line 2
map.addLayer(mapLayer);
```

If I comment the Comment Line 1 and 2, tile layers load, but if I uncomment any of one line, tile layer doesn't load.

Do anyone know the exact reason and the solution for it??
P.S : I am using openlayers v4.6.4

Comment: can you add how you defined (extent), because you should define it as your map projection and boundaries

Comment: `var ne = ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseFloat(image.north), parseFloat(image.east)]);
    var sw = ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseFloat(image.south), parseFloat(image.west)]);
    var extent = [sw[0], sw[1], ne[0], ne[1]];`

And these extents work properly with image layer, it only has a problem with tile layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and hit & trials. I found out that I was using the wrong map source class to initialize the map Source.

The correct code classes are:

```
var mapSource = new ol.source.TileImage({
        url: layerUrl
});
var mapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: mapSource,
        zIndex: parseInt(image.zindex),
        visible: true,
        'imageId': image.imageId
});
map.addLayer(mapLayer);
mapLayer.setExtent(extent);
```

I hope this will help someone going through the same issue.